# rsync or cp for coping debs ans settings

Tags: scripts, backup, rsync, copy, offline

Hi there I've written a script to backup my cache and etc directory. Just trying to decided whether or not to use cp or rsync. It's important that all files are copied with permissions preserved.

Comment: I recommend that you learn `rsync`. It is more powerful (but you can use `cp` too).

Answer (score 0):

rsync is ideal when the files are already partially copied and you just want to copy the changes or resume an aborted copy.  rsync also has a lot of options for filtering what to copy and controlling which file metadata gets copied.

cp may be faster if you are copying into an empty directory, or if there are no overlaps between the source and target, as it doesn't have to build a list up front.